# Android doesn't respect standalone usage of "user-scalable=no"

Tags: javascript, android, html, meta-tags

When I use "user-scalable=no" on an iPad, it doesn't break my layout by scaling it. It just disables zooming. That's great!
 However, on Android, it does scale my content, and it doesn't  disable zooming.
 Is there a workaround? I just want to disable the users ability to zoom on my page. (If it can be done with javascript, it's fine too)

Thaks in advance.